# Can this be considered Binomial variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I want to calculate the expectation and variance of this process, can I assume that this Binomial and find $E(x)=p(\mathtt{p}=0)E(z_1(n))+(1-p(\mathtt{p}=0))E(-(z_1(n)+z_2(n))/\sqrt{2})$ and apply the same for variance as in Binomial variables?

note that $z_1(n)$ and $z_2(n)$ are i.i.d normal distributed random variables with zero mean and $\sigma=1$

$x={\sum_{n=0}^{N/2-1}} z(n),$
\begin{equation}
z(n) = \begin{cases}
z_1(n), & \textrm{if} \, \mathtt{p}=0 ;\\
-(z_1(n)+z_2(n))/\sqrt{2} , & \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:detectedpolarmetric}
\mathtt{p}= \begin{cases} 0,
& \textrm{if} \,\, [z_1(n)-z_2(n) ] > z_2(n);\\
1,
& \,\, \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Given $z_1,z_2$, we can say $z \mid (z_1,z_2)$ is bernoulli, hence $x  \mid (z_1,z_2)$ is binomial

Comment: Just to make sure we get this right, it would be better if you gave the entire problem statement, including the part where $z_1$ and $z_2$ were described in the original wording. There appears to be some information missing, such as the words "independent identically distributed" or "iid".

Comment: yes they are iid RVs